# custom django command - help string not visible in shell completion

Tags: python, django, python-3.5, django-1.10

Following is a custom command I have written in following file
myapp/management/commands/create_myadmin.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Creates a superuser that can view the admin page'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username='myadmin')
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = User.objects.create_superuser('myadmin', 'myadmin@mymail.com', 'myadmin')
            user.save()
```

After this, I added myapp into INSTALLED_APPS in myproject/settings.py

My problem is that when I use autocomplete feature and list down commands starting with "create", it doesn't show help string against create_myadmin as shown below

```
python3 manage.py create (pressed tab here)

createcachetable   -- creates table for SQL cache backend
createsuperuser    -- create a superuser
create_admin_user (help string missing??)
```

I expected the string stored in help variable to be visible here.
Any quick pointers?

Update: I checked code for django/core/management/commands/createcachetable.py and the help text mentioned there doesn't match what I got above. Any idea where can one define the help text shown in above autocomplete?

Comment: strange, I don't see any help strings on autocomplete, only a list of possible commands. Is this a django 1.10-feature, maybe? (I have python3.4 and django 1.9.12)

Comment: can't you just do a search in the whole virtualenv for the string "creates table for SQL cache backend"? I don't think there will be many hits :)

Comment: @Ilja I already did that before posting here and didn't get any results

Comment: wow, nowhere in the whole python files? this is a miracle! :) (are you sure the search is correct, have you tried finding a string that you know is definitely there?). Anyway, sorry for my spamming, I don't have any notion here :)

Comment: grep -irn "creates table for SQL cache backend" ~/.virtualenvs/myvenv/ and 
grep -irn "creates table for SQL cache backend" /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages

Comment: I don't get the detailed list of autocomplete options you get. Maybe dig into  https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/extras/django_bash_completion to figure out how the list is built?

Comment: I am using Django1.10.3 and Python 3.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's bash and zsh completions run

```
./manage.py
```

to get a list of commands.  This list does not show help text.  This makes sense, since showing the help text would require importing all of the command modules.

Django's [zsh completion](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/django/django.plugin.zsh) includes some default help messages for built in commands.